# How to sort HashMap entries values by multiple properties Java8

Tags: java, java-8

How sort HashMap entries by multiple properties.

Suppose I have a map with key String and value as Object.

```
Map<String, UserMetrics> map = new HashMap<>
map.put("user10",new UserMetrics(1,100,111));
map.put("user3",new UserMetrics(10,330,444));
map.put("user11",new UserMetrics(333,100,555));
map.put("user1",new UserMetrics(1,111,433));

 public static class UsageMetrics implements Serializable {
        private long param1;
        private long param2;
        private long param3;....
 }
```

I want to sort users first by "param1" and then after by "param2"

result expected:<>

```
user10, UserMetrics(1,100,111)
user1,  UserMetrics(1,111,433))
user3,  UserMetrics(10,330,444));
user11, UserMetrics(333,100,555))
```

Comment: Try use `Comparator.comparing` and `thenComparing` function

Comment: @HadiJ Better `comparingLong` and `thenComparingLong`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following comparator for sorting:

```
Comparator
        .comparingLong(UserMetrics::getParam1)
        .thenComparingLong(UserMetrics::getParam2);
```

The difficulty is, however that you want to sort values, not keys. It seems also you need both keys and values. For this you could make and sort a copy of the entry set of your map. Something along the lines:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, UserMetrics>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(sortedEntries,
    Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
        Comparator
            .comparingLong(UserMetrics::getParam1)
            .thenComparingLong(UserMetrics::getParam2)));
```

Alternatively you can also use a sorted collection (like `TreeSet`) or a sorted stream - normally you can provide your own comparator to the "sorting things".

Also note that I'm using `comparingLong`/`thenComparingLong`, unlike other answers where people just used `comparing`/`thenComparing`. The problem with `comparing`/`thenComparing` is that if you have primitive types like `long`, `comparing`/`thenComparing` will essentially box them into wrapper types like `Long`, which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: This sorts by key. The OP wants to sort by value.

Comment: @HariMenon Ah, yes, my bad.

Comment: @HariMenon Corrected - let's remove our comments not to confuse people.

Comment: @lexicore , thanx :) !

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code. I have written by using `Employee` the s value object, so you can use your own `Object`  :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        HashMap<String, Employee> map = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Employee> sortedMap = map.entrySet()
                                             .stream()
                                             .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(Main::compare))
                                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                                                     (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

    }

    public static int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        return e1.getAge() - e2.getAge();
    }
}
```

**Edited**:
Here is another way you can use `Comparator#comparing` and `thenComparing` to sort.

```
Map<String, Employee> sortedMap = map.entrySet()
                                     .stream()
                                     .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(
                                             Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge)
                                                       .thenComparing(Employee::getSalary)))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue,
                                             (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: This does not address the core of the question which is: how to compare on multiple properties.

Comment: Main:: compare is a comparator you can put your logic as your wish. You can use multiple properties to develop your logic in public static int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) method.

Comment: Also sorting and then collecting to `HashMap` is useless since `HashMap` will neither retain sorting not insertion order. Use `LinkedHashMap` to retain insertion order.
(Update: this was corrected in the answer later on.)

Comment: You are right I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, of course you can put logic for comparing multiple properties in `Main.compare`. But you did not - despite it being the core of the question.

Comment: @lexicore I have modified my answer as per OP's need. Thanks for the suggestion .

Comment: `Map.Entry.comparingByValue` was new to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not an efficient data structure to sort by value. But if you really need to use it, you can try something like this:

```
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(entry -> entry.getValue().param1)
                                                         .thenComparing(entry -> entry.getValue().param2)
                                                         .thenComparing(entry -> entry.getValue().param3))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Better `comparingLong`/`thenComparingLong`.